# custom Google search (not Google Custom Search)

Tags: html, forms, search

Can someone please explain to me how this HTML works? I want to make something that would perform this search instead:
`https://www.google.com/search?q=%25s&client=firefox-b-1-d&biw=1366&bih=614&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:7680,iszh:4320`

I used Inspect Element to get this HTML from [InternetTIPS.com](https://www.internettips.com/flash-file-finder/):

```
<div><form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get" name="{5C088896-C4CC-4430-A6D8-9DC9D2BE379D}" target="_top"><input maxlength="255" name="q" size="35" type="text"><input name="Overview" type="hidden" value="1"><input name="internettips" type="submit" value="Find Flash Files"><input name="as_filetype" type="hidden" value="swf"></form></div>
```

See a demo of what the HTML does [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1H4EN52VMT0). Thank you in advance.

Comment: “I want to make something that would search this instead”: Do you mean that you want to create a search box like [https://www.internettips.com/flash-file-finder/ this one for flash] but you want yours to search for images of size 7680 × 4320px instead?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the only HTML you need to add a search form to a page that searches Google for images of a specific size:

```
<!-- This is a search form that will take us to
     https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:7680,iszh:4320&q=example
     when we search for . This search will show us only images, and
     those images will all be 7680 pixels wide and 4320 pixels tall.

     First we enclose everything in a <> whose  is everything that
     the search engine results page’s URI to the left of the question mark (?)
     in it -->
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">

   <!-- Next, we add the arguments that are added to the Google URI. For each
        part of the URI we want to build, we need an <> element with a
         attribute. -->

   <!-- build = -->
   <!--  needs to be set to , which tells Google we want only
        image search results. We add ="" to the input element
        because we don’t want the end user to have to choose that
        themself -->
   <input name="tbm" value="isch" type="hidden">

   <!-- build =:,:,: -->
   <!--  needs to be set to a three-part parameter that tells Google
        we’re doing a search for images of a certain size and what the
        dimensions we’re looking for are -->
   <input name="tbs" value="isz:ex,iszw:7680,iszh:4320" type="hidden">

   <!-- build = (but ours won’t specify "example" — the user
        will decide what to search for). This parameter’s  is
        not  but rather , which is what we’ll ask the user to
        enter. -->
   <!-- If we don’t want to prompt our users’ imaginations,
        we could remove ="" -->
   <!-- ="" means that the field where the user will input their
        query is about 35 characters wide on page load -->
   <input name="q" size="35" type="text" placeholder="puppies">

   <!-- Finally, we add the button the user can tap to enter their query,
        so our  is . We can set our value to whatever we want
        our button to say -->
   <input type="submit" value="Find images of size 7680px × 4320px">

 <!-- <> is the only element we have used that we must close -->
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas I really appreciate it, you help me to much XD